# Android load circle progres

Tags: android, loading, progressdialog

on my app i use a library gson to load on map more data the i recive by json response.
I use on gson request a progress dialog because the time to show all event is hight.
This is my code:

```
final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this,R.style.MyDialogTheme);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    pDialog.show();
    pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.caricamento));
```

I would like how i can replace progress dialog with a custom load circle on topbar as in this screenshot?

[image: Circle loading dialog]

Any help? Example or library for this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post styles.xml? You defined a custom theme

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by defining a custom view, with a progress bar in it, as part of your action bar.

This is a good tutorial that should help:
http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android